# Running SQL Server on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm considering using Amazon EC2 for a web app with a SQL Server back end.  Amazon charges extra for running an AMI with SQL Server pre-installed.  I already own a copy of SQL Server Enterprise Edition.  Is there anything stopping me from getting a standard Windows AMI and installing SQL Server on that?

Taking it one step further, what about creating my own Windows AMI with SQL Server?

The main issue is that I'm in the Microsoft BizSpark program and I get all the Microsoft software I can eat for 3 years as my company grows.  If I have to pay for Windows Server, SQL Server, etc. through Amazon, then it kind of defeats the purpose of why I worked hard to get into the program.

All of that said, I buy into the cloud computing model, so I'm more than happy to pay for the cloud services I use.  I just have a deal where the software is free for me for a period of time, so I'm trying to avoid paying twice so-to-speak.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can tell you technicaly it can work, and very well.

The devil is in the details with MS licence use. If you carry licenses through BizSpark you should probably just outline your use for the app to an MS rep to make sure your planned use is covered.

Big thing to keep in mind if you roll your own AWS images. You will want to make sure not to spin up more than you can fairly use under your license at one time.

I do like the fact that when you work with MS in their developer programs or go through certification they do seem to keep you stocked with software.